# Self-aware telephone network

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I heard about story from, say 50 years ago, about a telephone grid gaining self-awareness (and probably ending the world). Similar in nature to the original Frankenstein's monster: take a thing, add electricity and get life. Naively applying Volta's animal electricity with a line of thought like: "Hey, there is an electricity in the grid, so it could get alive." But now I could not find any mention of it.

Maybe it was even earlier and talking about a telegraph grid, not sure.

Any ideas about the source or if it actually exists?

Comment: There was a short story like this, written in (IIRC) the 1950s.  May have been the thematic forebear of Skynet from the *Terminator* franchise.

Comment: The earliest occurrence of the idea that the phone system might become self-aware is probably Clarke's "Dial 'F' for Frankenstein" from 1965.  I can't imagine that emergent intelligence was even a concept in the 1920s.

Comment: @DavidW arguably the concept of emergent intelligence has been with us since Pygmalion and Galatea - and Pinocchio.

Comment: @gowenfawr In neither of those cases is intelligence an _emergent_ phenomenon; spontaneous perhaps.

Comment: I thought more like a radio drama, which made some people believe it. Anyway, I'm interested in the story itself.

Comment: If I rememner correctly, it was similar in nature to the original Frankenstein's monster: take a thing, add electricity and get life. Naively applying Volta's animal electricity with the line of thought like: "Hey, there is an electricity in the grid, so it could get alive.".

Comment: @DavidW "Dial 'F' for Frankenstein" is pretty much it, probably I misremembered when it was written, thx. (If you can make it an answer, I'll accept it)

Comment: I also agree. The only story that I can remember that resembles this is Clarke's "Dial 'F' for Frankenstein".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible this is "[Dial 'F' for Frankenstein](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62000)" (1965) by Arthur C. Clarke.  It's a short story, probably under 2500 words, but it describes the situation the world awakes to in the hours after the telephone system becomes self-aware.

> At 0150 GMT on December 1, 1975, every telephone in the world started to ring.
>
> A quarter of a billion people picked up their receivers, to listen for a few seconds with annoyance or perplexity. Those who had been awakened in the middle of the night assumed that some far-off friend was calling, over the satellite telephone network that had gone into service, with such a blaze of publicity, the day before. But there was no voice on the line; only a sound, which to many seemed like the roaring of the sea; to others, like the vibrations of harp strings in the wind. And there were many more, in that moment, who recalled a secret sound of childhood-the noise of blood pulsing through the veins, heard when a shell is cupped over the ear. Whatever it was, it lasted no more than twenty seconds. Then it was replaced by the dial tone.

The idea is based on the concept that the complexity of the world's telephone exchanges now exceeds the complexity of the human brain:

> "And that's the whole point. Fifteen billion sounds a large number, but it isn't. Round about the 1960's, there were more than that number of individual switches in the world's autoexchanges. Today, there are approximately five times as many."
>
> "I see," said Reyner slowly. "And as from yesterday, they've all become capable of full interconnection, now that the satellite links have gone into service."

As for electricity, there's some talk about the baby needing food:

> "I see you're beginning to believe me," said Williams, with a certain grim satisfaction. "I can only answer your question by asking another. What does a newborn baby do? It starts looking for food." He glanced up at the flickering lights. "My God," he said slowly, as if a thought had just struck him. "There's only one food it would need-electricity."

And then everything shuts down...